# Blazor: counting characters in a textarea in Blazor (not .js)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a input textarea that I am limiting the character count on *(done)* that I also want to provide visual feedback for regarding how many characters are remaining.  Here's my textarea:

> `<textarea type="text" name="TheNameOfMyField" class="TheNameOfMyClass" value="" rows="2" maxlength="255"></textarea>`

I could do this in .js, no problem, but this case calls for a native solution & as much as I'd love 'the answer,' a finger pointed to resources that would enable me to ask fewer questions is equally welcome - just not the official MS documentation, I need it written at a level a UI developer working in a new environment can understand ::grin::

Also, if someone wanted to weigh-in on Blazor UI frameworks *(in so much that they may be able to help automate tasks like this one - it's the first one I could not locate at least a partial answer to online)*, I have the budget to buy into one, but I do not have the time to test several, so I am currently going without *(no contacts working in Blazor, everyone I know is C++, .JS, PHP, etc.)*.

In case I wasn't clear enough as to my objective, this isn't me *(it's .js & I need a c# Blazor solution)*, but conceptually it's pretty close *(except I'll be limiting the number of chars in the field, so no negative numbers)*:

> [https://www.itrelease.com/2011/05/count-characters-in-text-area-using-javascript/'](https://www.itrelease.com/2011/05/count-characters-in-text-area-using-javascript/%27)

Cheers!

Comment: Use MudBlazor if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 12):

Is something like this what you where looking for?

```
<textarea @bind="text"
          @bind:event="oninput"
          maxlength="@MAX_TEXT_COUNT" />
<label>Chars left: @(MAX_TEXT_COUNT - text.Count())</label>

@code {
    string text = "1234";
    const int MAX_TEXT_COUNT = 5;
}
```

The `@bind="text"` and `@bind:event="oninput"` will tell blazor to update the `text` variable on each keystroke.  The `maxlength="@MAX_TEXT_COUNT"` will prevent the user to input more symbols than `MAX_TEXT_COUNT`

The `<label>Chars left: @(MAX_TEXT_COUNT - text.Count())</label>` just prints out the difference.

Here is a snippet to test it online: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GYOrRkbb5532bvYW23

Comment: Easy to read & exactly what I needed!  I hit the useful button, but until my rep reaches 15, it won't show up.