# Why doesn't blazor server side app not re-render the page when @onkeyup is triggered

Tags: events, blazor-server-side

My Blazor server side component is supposed to count the characters in a text area and display the count.  The component is:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <textarea @onkeyup="TextUpdate" @bind="CommentText" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
    <p>Characters: @Characters</p>
</div>

@code {
    private string CommentText{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string Characters{ get; set; } = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Characters = "0";
    }

    private void TextUpdate()
    {
        Characters = CommentText.Length.ToString();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

I thought the number of characters displayed would update each time I typed a character in the text area.  However, nothing happens.

If I put a breakpoint inside the method TextUpdate(), the number of characters is updated correctly.

Am I using @onkeypress incorrectly?

I want to count the characters in a textarea, display the count and update the count as each character is typed.

Comment: It is not because of `@onkeypress` but because of `@bind`. It will only update `CommentText` when losing focus. If you want to get the modifications directly, you need to update the value on each input. Be careful, updating on each input may create some laggy results (when badly handled) on Blazor server, because of network time or long calculations.

Comment: I also found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163816/blazor-counting-characters-in-a-textarea-in-blazor-not-js.